# Postal add custom header

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sendgrid, postal

I am using Postal.NET for email in my C# MVC application:

http://aboutcode.net/postal/

I am using SendGrid for sending out emails.
Sendgrid requires custom header arguments to be sent using the "X-SMTPAPI" header attribute.

How can I add custom header values in Postal.NET? (e.g. myMessage.Headers.Add("X-SMTPAPI", jsonString);

Comment: Not sure why someone has to down vote the question when they really don't know how to answer. Can I know the reason for down voting this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you even understand my question? I very well know what SO is for. Thanks

Comment: Looks like a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107183/how-to-add-custom-header-to-postal-email

Comment: @Abhi Any updates? Solved the problem or used a workaround?

Comment: try this: http://aboutcode.net/postal/email-headers.html

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used this library, but it looks to me like you can just add headers in the view above the email.  That is the view you create contains the entire email--including headers.  In the documentation you can see that To: and From: are included in the view.  This is from the documentation:

```
To: @ViewBag.To
From: lolcats@website.com
Subject: Important Message

Hello,
You wanted important web links right?
Check out this: @ViewBag.FunnyLink

<3
```

So I think you could likely do something like:

```
X-SMTPAPI: @ViewBag.jsonAPIString
To: @ViewBag.To
From: lolcats@website.com
Subject: Important Message

Hello,
You wanted important web links right?
Check out this: @ViewBag.FunnyLink

<3
```

Comment: This worked for me using the Reply-To header. Thanks.

Comment: This was helpful. In my case, the header was converted to lowercase, so I needed to adjust my Outlook rule accordingly from "X-SMTPAPI: Blah blah" to "x-smtpapi: Blah blah".